# XSB Prolog: write my own setof function

Tags: list, prolog, xsb

I need to get, from a keyboard input (list), a list without duplicates but without using the inbuild setof (or any other inbuild functions) in XSB prolog.

How do i write my own setof function?

Input and output should look like this:

```
|?-list([a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,e,f],L).  

L=[a,b,c,d,e,f];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list(A,B) :- sort(A,B).`

Comment: i updated the post, we can't use any inbuild functions which puts sort out of the equasion

Comment: do you how to write member/2 ?

Comment: i know how to use member/2, but I think it's also inbuild, or am I wrong? this should be all written by myself..

Comment: Write a `list/2` based upon the existence of a `member/2` predicate (call it `mem` or `has_element` or something not built in), then write the `mem/2` or `has_element/2` predicate, which is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using member/2 it's so easy: just make a copy of each element, with a recursive list/2, checking the head of input list it's not already in the target list. Checking *could* be performed by member/2, you will need to write your own... The entire program should be 4 lines of code.